# Where to put a JavaScript alert override so that all pages can use it without importing a *.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert

Where do I put a JavaScript alert override so that all pages can use it without importing a JavaScript file?

I've overridden the alert method. I want to be able to use it from any .aspx page without importing it on each separate page.

Comment: overwrite a javascript function without writing any javascript... no.

Comment: I didn't say without writing any js but without importing, it's not the same. Check out the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all of the JavaScript code in the code behind and register it with `Page.RegisterStartup`.

For example, put it in the master page or from a page from which that all others pages derive. But it's not a good idea to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot override client side code without sending the override to the client. So what you want is impossible.

Comment: Unless you write your own, closed source browser, and get the majority of the world's population to use it.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem — The browser itself is client code though :)

Comment: true, but it wouldn't require including a js file... up to the OP which of the two options will be the easiest to implement. writing his own chromium spin off, or including a couple of lines of JS